# Using global variables in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Instead of this:

```
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Host = 'smtp.demo-server.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = 'demo-port';
$mail->Username = 'demo-email@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'demo-password';
```

I would like to keep the values in a separate file and use variables instead:

```
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Host = echo $server; // also tried without echo
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port = echo $port;
$mail->Username = echo $username; 
$mail->Password = echo $password;
```

I'm already using output buffering, have set the global scope, and the variable values contain the quotes. Still not working.

Comment: It looks like you want ENV variables. Very common thing :)

Comment: A first hit example: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: Remove `echo` when you assign value,
your final value like this:  `$mail->Host = $server;`

Comment: What sense is `$mail->Host = echo $server;` supposed to make? The equivalent to `$mail->Host = 'smtp.demo-server.com';` using a variable `$server` that contains the value `smtp.demo-server.com`, would simply be `$mail->Host = $server;`

Comment: @CBroe, I had tried the solitary variable at first. That didn't work. Adding `echo` was just an experiment, thinking that maybe this library worked differently.

Comment: Editor: Setting the global scope *"in PHP"* isn't the problem. Getting global variables to work *in PHPMailer* is. That's why I rejected your edit suggestion.

Comment: Why do you want to use global variables for this? Most current tutorials explicitly tell newbees to avoid them. It could be better to use a factory pattern for this instead

Comment: @NicoHaase, upgrading the code to ENV variables or factory pattern is a project for another day. For now, I'm trying to understand why global variables aren't working in PHPMailer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, global variables are working in PHPMailer as they are working everywhere else in PHP.  Have you tried using your favorite debugger, ot even `var_dump`, to check for the contents of these variables during runtime?

Comment: This all makes very little sense. Your second example is not valid PHP code, and won't even run. There is no such thing as "setting the global scope": you're in it by default. You don't show how you're loading the variables that are set in the other file. Output buffering has nothing to do with this because there is no output to buffer. The fact that you're using PHPMailer has no bearing on where your values come from, and PHPMailer will accept input from anything in scope, including globals – but setting them correctly is your responsibility.

Comment: @Synchro, *"You don't show how you're loading the variables that are set in the other file."* This turned out to be the problem. Although the variables were loaded onto the web page, the user-generated modal dialog box containing PHPMailer needed the variables to be loaded again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, kindly read **@Synchro**'s comment.

- Create a php file if you've not done that already (eg. `mail_config.php`) and declare your variables in it.
- Require/Include the `mail_config.php` file in your "main" file (the file that will send the mail eg. `send_mail.php`).
- Assign the PHPMailer props to their respective variables from the
  `mail_config.php` file in the `send_mail.php` file.

**Example**

`mail_config.php`

```
<?php

$server   = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$port     = 465;
$username = 'test@gmail.com';
$password = '123456';

?>
```

`send_mail.php`

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// require the settings file. This contains the settings
require 'path/to/mail_config.php';

// require the vendor/autoload.php file if you're using Composer
require 'path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

// require phpmailer files if you're not using Composer
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host          = $server;
    $mail->SMTPAuth      = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure    = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; // 'ssl'
    $mail->Port          = $port;
    $mail->Username      = $username;
    $mail->Password      = $password;

    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', "Sender's Name"); // sender's email(mostly the `$username`) and name.
    $mail->addAddress('test@example.com', 'Stackoverflow'); // recipient email and optional name.

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Read more https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Good answer, and thanks for the props!